# Hibernate: specifying which column in parent entity <join/> should use

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

I have the following  entity in my HBM file:

```
<join table="v_price_change_current_prices" fetch="join" inverse="true">
    <key column="product_color_id" />
    <property name="oldMSRP" column="msrp" />
    <property name="oldList"  column="list" />
</join>
```

my PRICE_CHANGE table has an ID column (primary key) and a PRODUCT_COLOR_ID column.

I would like the SQL Hibernate produces to join V_PRICE_CHANGE_CURRENT_PRICES to PRICE_CHANGE.PRODUCT_COLOR_ID, like so:

```
    SELECT * from PRICE_CHANGE a, V_PRICE_CHANGE_CURRENT_PRICES b 
where a.product_color_id=b.product_color_id
```

But its joining to PRICE_CHANGE.ID instead

```
    SELECT * from PRICE_CHANGE a, V_PRICE_CHANGE_CURRENT_PRICES b 
where a.product_color_id=b.product_color_id
```

Is there any way to tell the  element to to use PRICE_CHANGE.PRODUCT_COLOR_ID instead of PRICE_CHANGE.ID?

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, this might be doable using a `property-ref` in the `<key>` element:

> #### [5.1.21. Key](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-key)
>
> The `<key>` element has featured a few
>   times within this guide. It appears
>   anywhere the parent mapping element
>   defines a join to a new table that
>   references the primary key of the
>   original table. It also defines the
>   foreign key in the joined table:
>
> ```
> <key
>         column="columnname"                      (1)
>         on-delete="noaction|cascade"             (2)
>         property-ref="propertyName"              (3)
>         not-null="true|false"                    (4)
>         update="true|false"                      (5)
>         unique="true|false"                      (6)
> />
> ```
>
> 1. `column` (optional): the name of the foreign key column. This can also
>      be specified by nested 
>      element(s).
> 2. `on-delete` (optional - defaults to noaction): specifies whether the
>      foreign key constraint has
>      database-level cascade delete enabled.
> 3. **`property-ref` (optional): specifies that the foreign key refers
>      to columns that are not the primary
>      key of the original table. It is
>      provided for legacy data.**
> 4. `not-null` (optional): specifies that the foreign key columns are not
>      nullable. This is implied whenever the
>      foreign key is also part of the
>      primary key.
> 5. `update` (optional): specifies that the foreign key should never be
>      updated. This is implied whenever the
>      foreign key is also part of the
>      primary key.
> 6. `unique` (optional): specifies that the foreign key should have a unique
>      constraint. This is implied whenever
>      the foreign key is also the primary
>      key.

But I'm not sure this is actually implemented (see [HHH-551](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-551), [HHH-1829](http://opensource.atlassian.com/projects/hibernate/browse/HHH-1829)).

An alternative if you really don't want to use a shared primary key would be to use composition and a "real" [one-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone) association instead.

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Documentation

  - [5.1.13. One-to-one](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-onetoone)
  - [5.1.20. "Join"](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-join)
  - [5.1.21. Key](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-key)